# TypeError : 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

i was working with face mesh module of opencv to detect my face
when i try to run it on my code editor it show
"landmarks = landmark_points(1).landmark" this list as not callable

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

from cv2 import _registerMatType


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh()

while True: 

    _, frame = cam.read()

    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    #to get face detected
    output = face_mesh.process(rgb_frame)
    landmark_points = output.multi_face_landmarks
    
    #to get coordinates of face 
    if landmark_points:
        landmarks = landmark_points(1).landmark
        for landmark in landmarks:
            x = landmark.x
            y = landmark.y
            print(x, y)

    #frame display
    cv2.imshow('face detection', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

        break

cam.release

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the code work properly if we replace the coordinate section with "print(landmark_points)"
but i can not use the then result for my purpose, as i want it in (x,y) format

tried some sources but could not understand problem.
can some one provide solution with expanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`landmark_points` is a list. `landmark_points(1)` attempts to "call" it like a function. Did you mean `landmark_points[1]`? That accesses an element in a list with index `1`.

Note that `landmark_points[1]` is a second element, you probably want `landmark_points[0]` (first element)

Comment: yes I mean the same

Comment: got my mistake and solved it

Comment: voting to close as a **typo**. so should you.